# How to animate a 3D plot, defined with three functions x=(), y=(), z=()?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation, matplotlib-3d

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d as Axes3D

r = 20
h = 1.7
phi = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, 1000)
theta = np.linspace(-np.pi/4, np.pi/4, 1000)
#theta = np.arcsin(0.524)
x = r * np.cos(phi)
y = r * np.sin(phi) * np.cos(theta) - h * np.sin(theta)
z = r * np.sin(phi) * np.sin(theta) + h * np.cos(theta)

fig = plt.figure('Parametric pancake')
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.plot(x, y, z, '-r', linewidth = 3)

ax.set_xlabel('X', fontweight = 'bold', fontsize = 14)
ax.set_ylabel('Y', fontweight = 'bold', fontsize = 14)
ax.set_zlabel('Z', fontweight = 'bold', fontsize = 14)


plt.title('Parametric pancake', fontweight = 'bold', fontsize = 16)

plt.show()
```

This code draws the plot, defined by the x, y and z equations. That is great, but I need to draw it, i.e. to have a point that draws the plot as it moves and not have a plot, thats already drawn. How do I make that happen? Furthermore, I need the plot to move periodically - the angle phi to continue to rotate and angle theta to move harmonically from -90 degrees to +90 degrees kind of like a pendulum. And the last thing is how do I make the point move in a loop so it does not stop when the plot is drawn, but continues to move along that plot?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `animate` callback to update the data.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d as Axes3D
import matplotlib.animation as animation

r = 20
h = 1.7
N=1000
phi = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, N)
theta = np.linspace(-np.pi/4, np.pi/4, N)
#theta = np.arcsin(0.524)
x = r * np.cos(phi)
y = r * np.sin(phi) * np.cos(theta) - h * np.sin(theta)
z = r * np.sin(phi) * np.sin(theta) + h * np.cos(theta)

fig = plt.figure('Parametric pancake')
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.set_xlim(x.min(),x.max())
ax.set_ylim(y.min(),y.max())
ax.set_zlim(z.min(),z.max())

pltdata, = ax.plot(x[:1], y[:1], z[:1], '-r', linewidth = 3)
lastPoint, = ax.plot(x[0], y[0], z[0], 'b', marker='o')
txt = ax.text(x[0], y[0], z[0]+0.5, 'i=0')

ax.set_xlabel('X', fontweight = 'bold', fontsize = 14)
ax.set_ylabel('Y', fontweight = 'bold', fontsize = 14)
ax.set_zlabel('Z', fontweight = 'bold', fontsize = 14)


plt.title('Parametric pancake', fontweight = 'bold', fontsize = 16)

def animate(i):
    pltdata.set_data(x[:i+1], y[:i+1])
    pltdata.set_3d_properties(z[:i+1])
    lastPoint.set_data(x[i:i+1], y[i:i+1])
    lastPoint.set_3d_properties(z[i:i+1])
    txt.set_text(f"{i=}")
    txt.set_x(x[i])
    txt.set_y(y[i])
    txt.set_z(z[i]+0.5)
    return [pltdata, lastPoint, txt]

theAnim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=N, interval=100, blit=True, repeat=False)
plt.show()
#theAnim.save('out.gif')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, your code worked wonderfully. But since all the equations are harmonic, is it possible to make the point go past the end point to continue drawing the plot? For example making it draw util the press of a mouse or button to stop it? And additionally, can i store the coordinates of all the points to a text file?

Comment: They are not harmonic. Well, yes, they are. But I mean, in the range you provide, they do not repeat. So you have to change your boundaries first. So that θ goes from ? to ?+2π.

Comment: Then, repeat=True instead of False

Comment: For press of a mouse or button, you have to ask another question for that. Firstly, I don't know the answer (never played with any interaction callback with matplotlib). Secondly, even if I did, it is better, for future user, that each question deals with a single issue.

Comment: Likewise for saving data. Unless you are just looking for `np.savez('file.npz', x=x, y=y, z=z)`, and then `npz=np.load('file.npz'); x=npz['x']; y=npz['y']; z=npz['z']` (not that it should be in another question. But that other question would most certainly be a duplicate)